# MariaBackup questions

Tags: mariadb, galera

I have installed MariaDB 10.2.26 +Galera on 3 nodes, and installed MariaBackup 10.2.26 on the 4th server.

I want to backup the data of galera cluster to the 4th server using MariaBackup, but backup log infinitely loop shows  `[00] 2019-08-16 03:02:18 >> log scanned up to (1620043)`   and never ends.

so what is the problem about it?

my backup command running on 4th server is :

```sh
sudo  mariabackup --backup --target-dir=/home/worddba/ --user=usera  --host="one node of galera node"  --port=3306 --password="password"
```

Comment: seems Mariabackup doesnot support backup database on remote server. but its documents said --host parameter means "Defines the host for the MariaDB Server you want to backup.". but whatever, it only can backup local database....

Answer (score 0):

When adding a node to a Galera cluster, configure it and let it do its own "SST" to copy the data over from a 'donor' node of its choosing.  Don't bother with any kind of backup.